# java Collection listIterator

Tags: java

Как понял, listIterator изначально указывает начало списка, то есть  следующий код не работает(однако если перед этим циклом написать такой же ,только с hasNext и next,а потом уже цикл указанный ниже,то все работает).Как перенести итератор в конец списка.

```
     ListIterator listIterator = list.listIterator();
        while (listIterator.hasPrevious()){
            System.out.println(listIterator.previous());
        }
```

Comment: `list.listIterator(list.size())`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо просто передать в метод listIterator()  list.size() как параметр.
спасибо за ответ!